# Classifying text using RNN keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to understand [RNN for text classification using keras/tensorflow](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/). Currently it works to classify a positive / negative sentiment. How could I change it to some other class? For example, 2 classes, `Question` or `Not-Question`.

```
    # LSTM for sequence classification in the IMDB dataset
    import numpy
    from keras.datasets import imdb
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import LSTM
    from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
    from keras.preprocessing import sequence
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    numpy.random.seed(7)

    # load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
    top_words = 5000

    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

    # truncate and pad input sequences
    max_review_length = 500
    X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)

    X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)
    # create the model
    embedding_vecor_length = 32
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
    # Final evaluation of the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` in the last layer with `loss='binary_crossentropy'`, you are making a binary, 2 class classification. So you can use the same model to learn question, no-question setup.

If you want more than 2 classes, then we often use `Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')` and `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` which produces a probability distribution over possible classes. In fact, binary classification is just a special case of `Dense(2, activation='softmax')` where the classes are `[1,0]` and `[0,1]', i.e the one-hot encoding of the target class.

Comment: Okay. I have two directories named 'question` and `non-question` both for test and training. How could I load that data?